# Grouping lists by common elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm looking for a clever/fast C++ algorithm, which would allow me to do grouping of several lists of objects when they contain common objects inside. Let's say I have N lists, each containing 1..M objects (O) associated with one element E:

```
[O1, O2]     -> E1
[O3]         -> E2
[O1, O4, O5] -> E3
[O2, O5]     -> E4
[O3, O6]     -> E5
```

I wish to rearrange them into the following:

```
[O1, O2, O4, O5] -> [E1, E3, E4]
[O3, O6]         -> [E2, E5]
```

The result has all common objects grouped together with all associated elements. No object is shared in the end between lists.

Comment: So, what have you tried? How do you read your input data?

Comment: Have you considered [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)? See [When does using a std::multimap make sense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342445/when-does-using-a-stdmultimap-make-sense)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each object, calculate which elements contain it.

i.e.

```
01 -> [E1, E3]
02 -> [E4]
03 -> [E2, E5]
04 -> [E3]
05 -> [E3, E4]
06 -> [E5]
```

These lists induce a graph: there's a vertex per element, and two vertices are connected if the corresponding elements show up in the same list.

[image]

It seems to me that what you want to calculate are the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of the graph.

Comment: What if objects O were used as nodes? Helpers like boost::graph::connected_components could generate object groups in linear time and simple O->E multimap could then be used to generate element groups for each object group. Haven't had chance to test it yet, so I don't know if it's a correct approach.