# How can I detect common elements lists and groupe lists with at least 1 common element?

Tags: python, pandas, list, networkx

I have a Dataframe with 1 column (+the index) containing lists of sublists or elements.
I would like to detect common elements in the lists/sublists and group the lists with at least 1 common element in order to have only lists of elements without any common elements.
The lists/sublists are currently like this (exemple for 4 rows):

```
                 Num_ID
Row1   [['A1','A2','A3'],['A1','B1','B2','C3','D1']]`

Row2   ['A1','E2','E3']

Row3   [['B4','B5','G4'],['B6','B4']]

Row4   ['B4','C9']
```

n lists with no common elements (example for the first 2):

```
['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','C3','D1','E2','E3']
['B4','B5','B6','C9','G4']
```

Comment: Try out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503479/grouping-lists-by-common-elements. it's similar almost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NetworkX`'s [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) method for this. Here's how I'd approach this adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886120/union-of-sublists-with-common-elements/53886179#53886179) solution:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations, chain

df= pd.DataFrame({'Num_ID':[[['A1','A2','A3'],['A1','B1','B2','C3','D1']], 
                            ['A1','E2','E3'], 
                            [['B4','B5','G4'],['B6','B4']], 
                            ['B4','C9']]})
```

Start by flattening the sublists in each list:

```
L = [[*chain.from_iterable(i)] if isinstance(i[0], list) else i 
       for i in df.Num_ID.values.tolist()]

[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D1'],
 ['A1', 'E2', 'E3'],
 ['B4', 'B5', 'G4', 'B6', 'B4'],
 ['B4', 'C9']]
```

Given that the lists/sublists have more than 2 elements, you can get all the length 2 combinations from each sublist and use these as the network edges (note that edges can only connect two nodes):

```
L2_nested = [list(combinations(l,2)) for l in L]
L2 = list(chain.from_iterable(L2_nested))
```

Generate a graph, and add your list as the graph edges using add_edges_from. Then use connected_components, which will precisely give you a list of sets of the connected components in the graph:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(L2)
list(nx.connected_components(G))

[{'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D1', 'E2', 'E3'},
 {'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'C9', 'G4'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a newbie I've to digest all the concepts here but a quick test with my data seems very good. Could you please tell me what should be done to put the resulting sets in a Dataframe with columns Set1, Set2, Set3... ? Thanks again, really impressed by your quick answer

Comment: Everything is fine. Grateful for eternity :-)